# What is movl to memory doing in this loop?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, reverse-engineering, disassembly, att

I'm doing some homework and I don't understand what this movl is doing (I think this is a for loop or something but i really don't understand)

Please help

```
   0x0000555555555238 <+46>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
   0x000055555555523d <+51>:    jmp    0x55555555524c <clave0+66>
   0x000055555555523f <+53>:    movslq %eax,%rdx
   => 0x0000555555555242 <+56>: movl   $0x0,(%rsp,%rdx,4)
   0x0000555555555249 <+63>:    add    $0x1,%eax
   0x000055555555524c <+66>:    cmp    $0xff,%eax
   0x0000555555555251 <+71>:    jle    0x55555555523f <clave0+53>
   0x0000555555555253 <+73>:    mov    $0x0,%eax
```

I tried googling but nothing seems to have the same format so im not sure what is exactly doing. I just know that is moving an int.

Comment: Which part is confusing? Did you look at [at&t effective address format](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/i386_002dMemory.html)? TL;DR: it's writing 32 zero bits to memory starting at address `rsp+rdx*4`

Comment: the confusing part for me is that i think is just a really long loop for no reason, unless that movl is doing something important (i think it might be a distraction the teacher placed lol)

Comment: It's not a very long loop, just 256 iterations. It's zeroing a block of 256 double words which can be important later.

Answer (score 0):

This movl instruction writes 4 bytes 0x00 to the logical address: rsp+rdx*4.

Equivalent Intel syntax is:

mov DWORD PTR [rsp+rdx*4], 0x00